# Azure Functions Core Tools vs CLI aka how to have the list of functions within a functionapp

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-cli, azure-functions-core-tools

I need to have the list of functions deployed into an Azure Function App from command line (to be honest I need it into an Azure Devops Pipeline).

It seems that the only way to have this info is throught the command line `func azure functionapp list-functions`  available in `azure-functions-core-tools@3`

Or in other words, I was unable to do the same thing with `az functionapp ...` which seems to be the equivalent of `func` for Azure CLI.

I there any (other then `func`) easy way to have the list of functions deployed with an Azure Function App?

Comment: You can use the below PowerShell script to list the functions under a particular function app 
## script ##
 Connect-AzAccount
$ResourceGroupName = '<resource-group'
$AppName = '<functionName'
 $Params = @{
    ResourceGroupName = $ResourceGroupName
    ResourceType      = 'Microsoft.Web/sites/functions'
    ResourceName      = $AppName
    ApiVersion        = '2021-01-15'
}
Get-AzResource @Params


Here is the reference output for the above PowerShell script 
https://imgur.com/hSbVVos

Comment: @VenkateshDodda-MT thanks for the interesting comments. Honestly I'm not into powershell scripts, any suggestion to do this in python?